# Creating vertical thin coloured strips on sphere

Tags: color

I have attached an image with an explanation of the issue I have.
https://www.mediafire.com/view/qs0nu64aov4rou8/Vertical_Strips.PNG/file

Comment: hello, please give the full explanation in text here and also display the image

Comment: For your information: You can add images to your question(s) by using the "image" button in the upper menu bar of the question form. It's better to do this because the image will appear with your question (no link to follow) and the image will stay with your question possibly helping others in the future. Happy Blending.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

-Loop select horizontal line

-Select similar (shift + G) > direction

-Delete edges

-Add modifier > Skin

-Select all edges > Ctrl + A to resize the thickness of skin

(optional)

-add subdivision modifier to smooth things out

Comment: Hi. I am using Blender 2.8 and I don't see those procedural items on the menu. Are you using another version ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use bevel:

- Select a ring of edge loops with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> right click.

[image]

- Select the edge loops with the *Select* > *Edge Loops* function.

[image]

- Bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]

- Keep it as it is or extrude with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Region*.

[image]

- Give the faces the material you want.

Comment: Hi. I'm using Blender 2.8. I don't see the Edge Loops function on this version.